# How to draw raster console fonts in GDI?

Tags: winapi, gdi, bitmap-fonts

How do I draw the raster fonts used by the Windows console in a GDI application?  For instance, the 8x8 fixed font as shown in this screenshot.[image: Command Prompt Properties - raster fonts]

Can these fonts be used via the CreateFont() API, or is there some special way that Windows loads these fonts?

Answer (score 1):

The console uses `"fixed width fonts"`, such as `"Courier New"` (available in all Windows version) or `"Consolas"` (available since Vista).

Fixed width fonts are not necessarily raster. To use raster fonts, enumerate fonts to find a raster font such as `"Terminal"` or `"Fixedsys"`. You have to use the right size (example, 18 for `"Terminal"` font) otherwise Windows may substitute a different font and resize. There are also issues with DPI settings. If program is not DPI aware then magnification will occur if work station has high DPI settings.

```
case WM_PAINT: 
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    auto hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    auto hfont = CreateFont(-18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        ANSI_CHARSET,
        OUT_DEVICE_PRECIS,
        CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
        DEFAULT_QUALITY,
        DEFAULT_PITCH,
        L"Terminal");

    auto oldfont = SelectObject(hdc, hfont);

    RECT rc = { 0,0,100,300 };
    DrawText(hdc, L"Test 123", -1, &rc, DT_LEFT | DT_TOP);

    SelectObject(hdc, oldfont);
    DeleteObject(hfont);

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Regarding DPI settings, I plan on drawing to an offscreen bitmap (with a memory HDC rather than BeginPaint/EndPaint).  How do I pick a specific bitmap font regardless of monitor DPI settings?

Comment: So in my testing I am reliably picking a size regardless of DPI however I had to make the following changes:  
cWidth had to be specified, so to select the 8x8 font I had to have the first two parameters be `-8,-8`, and the other change I had to make to that example was to replace `ANSI_CHARSET` with `OEM_CHARSET` for the iCharSet parameter.

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you are doing, what the output looks like, and what you expect the output should look like.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was similar to Barmak's answer, with the difference that both width and height are specified, so to create a font for the 8x8 raster font I use the following code:

```c
hfont = CreateFont(-8, -8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, OEM_CHARSET, OUT_DEVICE_PRECIS,
        CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, _T("Terminal"));
```

Specifically, both the height and width must be specified, and the OEM_CHARSET charset must be specified, in order to select one of the Raster Fonts.

My intent is to render to a DirectDraw surface (`IDirectDrawSurface7::GetDC()`) then subsequently paint that surface to the primary, as shown here:
[image]
With a bit of trickery involving multiple passes I added a bit of a shadow effect to the text, however that is outside the scope of my original question.